# hadoop & webhdfs access op = open is getting 404 not found

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, webhdfs

'm facing an issue with the WebHDFS access on my Amazon EC2 machine. I have installed hadoop with this *https://letsdobigdata.wordpress.com/2014/01/13/setting-up-hadoop-1-2-1-multi-node-cluster-on-amazon-ec2-part-2/*

I can retrieve the file status from my local machine in the browser (chrome) with following http request:

http://:50070/webhdfs/v1/user/admin/file.csv?op=GETFILESTATUS
This works fine but if I try to open the file with ?op=OPEN, then it redirects me to the private DNS of the machine, which I cannot access:

http://:50075/webhdfs/v1/user/admin/file.csv?op=OPEN&namenoderpcaddress=:8020&offset=0
I also tried to get access to WebHDFS from the AWS machine itself with this command:

[ec2-user@ conf]$ curl -i http://localhost:50070/webhdfs/v1/user/admin/file.csv?op=GETFILESTATUS
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
Does anyone know why I cannot connect to localhost or why the OPEN on my local machine does not work? Unfortunately I couldn't find any tutorial to configure the WebHDFS for a Amazon machine.

Thanks in Advance